# How to visualize recent orders for a crypto exchange

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I would like to visualize the recent trades from a crypto exchange.
I use ccxt to get the recent trades:

```
import ccxt
binance = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': 'KEY',
    'secret': 'SECRET'
})

the_tape = binance.fetch_trades('ETHBUSD')
```

here is what my API call returns:

```
[
  {
    'info': {
      'a': '157594085',
      'p': '3224.42000000',
      'q': '0.00820000',
      'f': '198701298',
      'l': '198701298',
      'T': '1631528034145',
      'm': False,
      'M': True
    },
    'timestamp': 1631528034145,
    'datetime': '2021-09-13T10:13:54.145Z',
    'symbol': 'ETH/BUSD',
    'id': '157594085',
    'order': None,
    'type': None,
    'side': 'buy',
    'takerOrMaker': None,
    'price': 3224.42,
    'amount': 0.0082,
    'cost': 26.440244,
    'fee': None
  },
  {
    'info': {
      'a': '157594086',
      'p': '3224.48000000',
      'q': '0.10080000',
      'f': '198701299',
      'l': '198701302',
      'T': '1631528034545',
      'm': False,
      'M': True
    },
    'timestamp': 1631528034545,
    'datetime': '2021-09-13T10:13:54.545Z',
    'symbol': 'ETH/BUSD',
    'id': '157594086',
    'order': None,
    'type': None,
    'side': 'buy',
    'takerOrMaker': None,
    'price': 3224.48,
    'amount': 0.1008,
    'cost': 325.027584,
    'fee': None
  },
```

And I make it into a DataFrame:

```
new_tape = [{'datetime': el['datetime'], 'side': el['side'], 'price': el['price'],
             'amount': el['amount'], 'total': el['cost']} for el in the_tape]
```

This is my pandas DataFrame:

```
            datetime           side   price   amount       total
0    2021-09-13 09:34:01.042   buy   3208.97  0.0234    75.089898
1    2021-09-13 09:34:01.091   buy   3208.97  0.0200    64.179400
2    2021-09-13 09:34:01.148   buy   3208.97  0.1444   463.375268
3    2021-09-13 09:34:01.242   buy   3209.16  0.6205  1991.283780
4    2021-09-13 09:34:01.420   sell  3209.00  0.2500   802.250000
```

I would like to get two histograms:
(1) cumulated histogram with two bars: total bought and total sold
(2) weighted histogram with the amounts bought and sold, something that would look like this:
[image: Weighted histogram]

I would like to use seaborn in order to be able to save the images and maybe upload them to a website or word document.

I found this code but I don't know how to adapt it and what "binwidth" is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title(f"Last update: {t} (ID: {last_update_id})")

sns.histplot(x="price", weights="quantity", hue="side", binwidth=binwidth, data=data, ax=ax)
sns.scatterplot(x="price", y="quantity", hue="side", data=data, ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel("Price")
ax.set_ylabel("Quantity")

plt.show()
```

Any help or suggestion as to how to best represent this data would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: [Freqtrade has some plotting code](https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/blob/develop/freqtrade/plot/plotting.py) that you could look at

Comment: @Sam thank you, I will check it out